# Phonegap / Cordova + Talkback resulting on actions being fired twice

Tags: angularjs, cordova, voiceover, talkback, angularjs-ng-touch

I'm working on an App with Phonegap + AngularJS and when i touch on any item on screen, the ScreenReader speaks twice.

I'm on android 4.4.2 with cordova + AngularJS = ngTouch.

Have Someone had this same problem?

On iOS with VoiceOver active everything works fine.

Comment: Can you add code snippet?

Comment: It's difficult to add some snippet because it's on all the app and only with talkback enabled.